# Found tag with a typo'd name. What do I do?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I was reviewing suggested edits when I came across an edit to a new tag wiki, [regex-spit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex-spit). It looks like it was just recently made by the author of the only question in the tag.

It looks like [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31919830/splitting-values-by-commas-that-are-outside-parentheses) was already edited to contain [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) and [split](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/split).

Given that this new tag is useless *and* has a typo, what can I (or the community) do with it? Burninate?